# "Payment not completed" with Apple Pay - can't get token

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

I am implementing Apple Pay using PassKit, I am showing the dialog the proper way and handling the delegate methods, but every time I use touch Id to verify a purchase it says "Payment not completed" and never reaches my delegate method `paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:completion:`. I did all of [these things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476470/431271) fully to set up apple pay, but I cant seem to get a token back to send to my payment gateway.

```
PKPaymentRequest *request = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
self.paymentRequest = request;
request.countryCode = @"US";
request.currencyCode = @"USD";
request.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa];
request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapabilityEMV;
request.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.*******";
request.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldPostalAddress;
request.requiredBillingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldPostalAddress;

request.paymentSummaryItems = [self paymentSummaryItems];
self.paymentPane = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
self.paymentPane.delegate = self;
if (self.paymentPane) {
    [self presentViewController:self.paymentPane animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Here is what I am seeing, and the screen just stays there and says "Try Again" over and over:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally got a token. I needed to enable 3DS as a payment processing capability:

```
request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapabilityEMV | PKMerchantCapability3DS;
```

That's what I get for copypasting someone else's code (http://goo.gl/uvkl8F). Strange because 3DS is 'required' according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentRequest_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PKPaymentRequest/merchantCapabilities):

> You must support 3DS; support of EMV is optional.

Why I have to explicitly state 3DS is supported by the merchant when it's required is beyond me.

Comment: I had the same error because the domain i registered was different from what i was passing in "get session" request. Just in case, someone else faces it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176397/error-apple-pay-not-completed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Credit card you setup on Passbook is verified...otherwise, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController will return nil.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176397/error-apple-pay-not-completed