# PKPaymentAuthorizationController not calling delegate methods and freezing when "Cancel" is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, siri, sirikit

In my Intents extension, I'm using the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` to allow the user to make a payment. I created a wrapper around it which looks like this:

```
class ApplePayModalController: NSObject {

  public typealias AuthorizationHandler = (ApplePayModalController, PKPayment, (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) -> Void

  private var onAuthorize: AuthorizationHandler?

  func present(paymentRequest: PKPaymentRequest, onAuthorize: @escaping AuthorizationHandler) {
    let controller = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
    self.onAuthorize = onAuthorize
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.present()
  }

}

extension ApplePayModalController: PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

  func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
    controller.dismiss()
  }

  func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
    guard let onAuthorize = self.onAuthorize else {
      return completion(.init(status: .failure, errors: nil))
    }

    onAuthorize(self, payment, completion)
  }

}
```

And this is where I'm getting the PKPaymentRequest that I'm using to present it:

```
  public func createPKRequest(order: Order) -> PKPaymentRequest {
    let paymentRequest = Stripe.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: PaymentRepository.merchantIdentifier, country: "US", currency: "USD")
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
      PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "HSCO", amount: 1.00),
      PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Phil", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: Double(order.price) / 100))
    ]
    paymentRequest.shippingType = .storePickup
    paymentRequest.requiredBillingContactFields = [PKContactField.postalAddress]

    return paymentRequest
  }
```

However, I'm having the following issues when I present the controller:

1. Pressing the 'cancel' button causes the entire controller to stop working. I can't change the payment method, it doesn't dismiss, and the 'pay' button stops responding as well. However, I can still tap outside of the controller to dismiss it
2. The delegate methods aren't firing––at all. I tried adding more delegate methods and those weren't firing either; because of this, I can't handle payment authorization.
3. The behavior of the controller when I try to pay with different cards is not consistent. Using an Apple Amex test card, attempting to pay will fail immediately; using an Apple test Visa, it gets stuck on 'processing' for 15-20 seconds before displaying an alert saying "Apple Pay Not Completed" ([Same as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176397/error-apple-pay-not-completed))

This is all running on an iPhone X, iOS 12.1.4, using Apple Pay in sandbox mode.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `ApplePayModalController` instance life cycle is longer than your payment process. Try with a static `ApplePayModalController` singleton.