# How can I increase the failure timeout of an apple Pay operation?

Tags: ios, applepay

In the current implementation, my payment takes a long time in some cases. Often users have an error like "Apple pay not completed". The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176397/error-apple-pay-not-completed) says that in iOS 11 this happens after 15-20 seconds, **can I increase this time**, if so, **how** ? If the payment has time to process during this time, the payment in apple pay is successful.

Comment: you can not, you should improve your payments time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible from what i know and what i found ,
the `onpaymentauthorized` method has to be called within 30 seconds , if not the payment is declined . Refer to this , in most cases you only have as much as 30 seconds .

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778020-onpaymentauthorized

Comment: Thanks a lot, we will optimize the payment process!

Answer (score 0):

While changing the failure timeout is impossible, there is still a workaround to avoid the *"Apple pay not completed"* message for cases when, for example, your API call processing the payment has extended timeout. (At the moment of writing this answer, on iOS 13, the ApplePay dialog would timeout itself in around 30 secs).

The trick is to set a one-time timer, which would dismiss the ApplePay dialog just before it decides to give up. Of course your app must always give user proper feedback when the purchase process ends (was it success or failure), 'cause ApplePay dialog won't be able to show anything after you dismiss it.

Example timer:

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 25, repeats: false) { _ in
    guard self.applePayBeingProcessed == true else { return }
    if let applePayVC = AppUtil.shared.topMostController() as? PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController {
        self.applePayHasTimeouted = true
        applePayVC.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

*`applePayBeingProcessed` is set to `true` in `paymentAuthorizationViewController(_:didAuthorizePayment:handler:)` and set back to `false` right after calling `handler(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult(status: paymentStatus, errors: [error]))` - so that the routine called by timer would be skipped when ApplePay dismissed in a normal way via `paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_:)`

** `applePayHasTimeouted` is later checked inside a completion of your payment processing API call, if `true` it means we need to perform actions, that are normally supposed to be performed inside `paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_:)` (because the latter will never be called after manually closing ApplePay dialog)

*** `topMostController()` method finds the controller from the top of hierarchy. How to do this is out of scope of current question, there lots of ways to do this, my favorite one is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629176/2650588).